# How to interchange first 2 words in a filename using bash

Tags: linux, bash

New to scripting, just wanted to interchange first 2 word in a all file names in a directory as follows:

From

```
A-B-Model-011818.xml
X-Y-Model-011818.xml
```

To

```
B_A-Model-011818.xml
Y_X-Model-011818.xml
```

I started with basic awk function and get desired output

```
echo "A-B-Model-011818.xml" | awk -F'[-.]' '{print $2"_"$1"-"$3"-"$4".xml"}'
```

but to apply this technique in bash (using for loop to ensure i find all .xml files and rename file) does not helped.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    cd Current_Directory

    for FILE in *.xml; do
     # NEWNAME =  $(awk -F'[-.]' '{print $2"_"$1"-"$3"-"$4".xml"}')
       NEWNAME = sed 's/\(.\)-\(.\)/\2_\1/'
       mv "$FILE" "$NEWNAME"
    done
```

Not sure if this is right way of using sed or awk function in loop.

Comment: About what u tried : you can't have empty spaces before and after '=' in a bash  affectation, the spaces are only for a test. Also, when you want to use a command in the right-hand side of an affectation, you have to quote it with backquotes (`)

Comment: Thanks. That fixed issue. I removed empty spaces before and after = and it worked.

Comment: It probably didnt work without backquotes or $(...) though.

Answer (score 1):

With **`prename`** (Perl rename) command:

```
prename -n 's/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])(-.*\.xml)/$2-$1$3/' *.xml
```

(remove `-n` option after you have ensured that the process goes as required)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by means of `sed`:

```
echo "A-B-Model-011818.xml" | sed 's/\(.\)-\(.\)/\2_\1/'
```

results in:

```
B_A-Model-011818.xml
```

Comment: I can achieve this by echo "A-B-Model-011818.xml" | awk -F'[-.]' '{print $2"_"$1"-"$3"-"$4".xml"}' as well. But how to use this in for loop script is kind of concering